# excel vba subroutine call fails

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

I have the following problem. I want to call a soubroutine for changing the background color for a cell range. The cell range is calculated with cells(1,1) and then the address is calculated to receive A1.

Before the subroutine is called I get the addresses for my cells like this:

```
Range1 = cells(4, 4).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
Range2 = cells(4, CellAmount - 1).Address(RowAbsolute:=False, ColumnAbsolute:=False)
```

I thought I need this because the subroutine is declared like this:

```
Sub SetBGLightGrey(cells As String)

    range(cells).Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 15921906
        .TintAndShade = 0
       .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Range 1 and Range 2 are strings and I concat it to a range declaration:

```
RangeArea = """" & Range1 & ":" & Range2 & """"
```

When I call my subroutine like this:

```
Call SetBGLightGrey(RangeArea)
```

I get the following error-message:

"Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed. I don't understand it because if I call the subroutine with the correct cell values:

```
Call SetBGLightGrey("D4:K4")
```

it works. It is string and of the same value. This simply cannot be can it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need quotes around RangeArea.

```
RangeArea = Range1 & ":" & Range2
```

But then, why would you want to pass ranges around as strings and then convert them back to ranges? Pass the range objects all the time.

```
Sub SetBGLightGrey(byval cells as range)
  With cells.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 15921906
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
  End With
End Sub 

SetBGLightGrey range(cells(4, 4), cells(4, CellAmount - 1))
```